# Convert MYSQL_ROW type to String

Tags: mysql, string

I am using the MYSQL C API and I have a MYSQL_ROW object that I would like to convert to a string.  Does anyone know how to do this? I haven't found anything in the API's doc yet.

string str = (string)row[0] <-- runtime error

P.S. I tried casting it to a string but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. `string` isn't a C datatype. You are probably looking for `char *`.
2. According to the [MySQL API Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-datatypes.html), MYSQL_ROW isn't null-terminated strings. You should use `mysql_fetch_lengths()` to copy your desired field to a new string.